# Least Area bounded

Tags: area

Area bounded by f(x) = $x^3/3$ - $x^2$ +a and the straight line x=0, x=2 and the x axis is minimum. Find a

[image]

This is the screen shot of the function when a=0.6.

Scrolling the value of "a" from 0 to 9, I  am finding the function to have least value between 0.6 to 0.7...How to prove this mathematically?

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how to calculate the area mathematically?

Comment: Yes. I believe it comes from integration of bounded functions

Comment: But with "a"as a parameter, how will it help us?

Comment: Correct! We can use integration. Maybe you can try using integration to find the area as a function of $a$, and then investigate this function.

Comment: Okay. Let me try then

Comment: I get a=2/3 when I set area to be zero. I think it fulfills the condition

Comment: if it is bounded by the $x$-axis, shouldn't $a$ be zero or lesser?